# How to chain on custom validations using Yup

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I want to add a .test() method to a validationSchema. The test is to look for common email domain  misspellings. For instance, to check if gmail was misspelled "gmial" or "gnail".

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object({    
         email: Yup.string().lowercase()
        .email('You have entered an invalid email')
        .required('This field is required')
        .test('test-name', 'Did you mean @gmail??????', function(value){
            if (value.includes('gmial' || 'gnail'))
                return this.createError('')
    })
<Formik>
      <Form>
        <div className='form-control'>
          <label htmlFor='email'>Email</label>
          <Field type='text' id='email' name='email' />
          <ErrorMessage name='email' component={TextError} />
        </div>
      </Form>
</Formik>
```

Answer (score 0):

Return a boolean result in your test.

```js
const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  email: Yup.string()
    .lowercase()
    .email('You have entered an invalid email')
    .required('This field is required')
    .test('Gmail?', 'Did you mean @gmail?', (value) => value.includes('gmial' || 'gnail')),
});
```